Why do I get ASP.NET Core 8.0 CORS error in Angular
I'm running an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API project and have no issues with the GET or POST methods, but with DELETE, I get this error:

alerts:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.mydomain.dom/controller/Delete?id=123' from origin 'https://angular.mydomain.dom' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In my Program.cs, I have the following code:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Configuration
var configuration = builder.Configuration;

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApiDbContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DbApiConnection"))
       .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information));

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ICountryRepository, CountryRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
    {
        policy
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});
builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();



From the docs

The call to UseCors must be placed after UseRouting, but before UseAuthorization. For more information, see Middleware order.

So move your app.UseCors() below app.UseRouting();

Just tried, didnt help. Getting the same error.

Did you miss this section from the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#enable-cors-with-endpoint-routing
When using endpoints like you are, you need to add RequireCors to the MapControllers call

@thorkia it didn't help either. There is something else wrong and its giving me grey hair. I had no problems when running with .net 6.0 this occured only after upgrading it to 8.0

Maybe try the [DisableCors] attribute on your delete method.
